# Ubuntu after bridging network no internet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn, bridge

I am running an Ubuntu server with OpenVPN and apache on it (`192.168.178.30`). The FritzBox (Router) is `192.168.178.1`. OpenVPN is is bridge mode. When I start the bridge using the OpenVPN shell script (bee below) ifconfig looks like this and **I have no internet connection anymore**:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.30  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:feb2:400  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:b2:04:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 22  bytes 2448 (2.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13  bytes 1310 (1.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:feb2:400  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:b2:04:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 112428  bytes 21475704 (21.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 21826  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 54705  bytes 14757275 (14.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 208  bytes 19137 (19.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 208  bytes 19137 (19.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tap0: flags=4355<UP,BROADCAST,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 6a:e5:9c:c5:4e:5f  txqueuelen 100  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

When disabling the bridge ifconfig looks like and **internet works** again:

```
eth0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.30  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:feb2:400  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:b2:04:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 112037  bytes 21430886 (21.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 21820  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 54532  bytes 14721454 (14.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 208  bytes 19137 (19.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 208  bytes 19137 (19.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

OpenVPN conenction work within the network – server is listening an running fine. But when using the DynDNS name and run over fritzbox (port 1194 is redirected) nothing happens – also the server cannot access google.de – so the internet connection is gone when bridge is started.

Here is the OpenVPN bridge-start (https://openvpn.net/community-resources/ethernet-bridging/#linuxscript) shell script with my IP settings:

```
#!/bin/bash

#################################
# Set up Ethernet bridge on Linux
# Requires: bridge-utils
#################################

# Define Bridge Interface
br="br0"

# Define list of TAP interfaces to be bridged,
# for example tap="tap0 tap1 tap2".
tap="tap0"

# Define physical ethernet interface to be bridged
# with TAP interface(s) above.
eth="eth0"
eth_ip="192.168.178.30"
eth_netmask="255.255.255.0"
eth_broadcast="192.168.178.255"

for t in $tap; do
    openvpn --mktun --dev $t
done

brctl addbr $br
brctl addif $br $eth

for t in $tap; do
    brctl addif $br $t
done

for t in $tap; do
    ifconfig $t 0.0.0.0 promisc up
done

ifconfig $eth 0.0.0.0 promisc up

ifconfig $br $eth_ip netmask $eth_netmask broadcast $eth_broadcast
```

Also bridge config should be correct:

```
brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.00155db20400   no          eth0 tap0
```

**Update**

I have seens that /etc/network/interfaces are disabled and netplan is active. The netplan config looks like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 192.168.178.30/24
      gateway4: 192.168.178.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1]
```

Should here br0 be defined (instead of eth0)? Tried that and seems that was the answer. Will observe that.

Comment: Yes, in order to act as a router, the bridge needs to have the outer ip address. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/319984. The last line of the openvpn script tries to do this, but that doesn't take netplan into account.

Comment: This already has netplan examples: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openvpn.html